# .Net existence: chicken and eggs?

Tags: c#, .net

There are several options for C#-based programs to determine which .Net version is installed. But is it possible to determine if .Net IS installed? I mean if I run C#-program on a machine without any .Net installed, I get the following error:

---

### Myprogram.exe - Application Error

### The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135). Click on OK to terminate the application.

### OK

Yes, I can write a wrapper (some external program or msi-package or somethins like that) but I'm wondering if I can do this sanity check from my C#-program? All I want is to check .Net existence and exit on failure with correct warning like "Microsoft .Net is required. Please install it bla-bla-bla".

Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: You are asking if it is possible for a C# program to check if it is possible to run C# programs? 'I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.'

Comment: Let's assume he's asking "How to pack a .NET executable inside a native one which checks if .NET is installed before launching its contents?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the preferred way to do this is to create an installer for your app and make the .Net Framework a pre-req that the installer checks for.

You can also include the .Net Framework re-distributable components so your installer will install it if it is not found.

[See this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419639/installing-net-framework-with-my-app-using-msi).

Answer (score 4):

If you create a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) installer and add the .NEt version you need as a prerequisite, then this check will be done for you when your users install your program for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

No, C# cannot check for the existence of .NET. It's like asking if you can write a program to check if the computer is turned on.

You'd need to write native code to check this, or more preferably, an installer that checks this.

Comment: It seems I have nothing to do except this. Thanks.

Comment: "It's like asking if you can write a program to check if the computer is turned on." made me lol but it's a great example :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bootstrapper Plug-in](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/applications/entry1325.aspx) and the framework will be bundled with your application.